# list's element draggable don't scroll the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have a list  "ul" that scrolls thanks to the fact that the elements are draggable

[1]Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/b68fn/

However as you can see it doesn't not work.I've seen many people having issues while trying to drag the element into another list, but I don't want that complicated. It seems to me the scroll property of draggable is there for that, isn't ?

```
$(".account_line").draggable({
        containment: '#TreeHierarchy',
        cursor: 'move',
        snap: '.account_line',
        helper: 'clone',
        scroll:true,
        scrollSensitivity:100
})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `position:relative` to `#TreeContainer` . 
Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/b68fn/1/